# The formal Group of the dual Abelian Variety

Tags: formal-groups, abelian-varieties

For an abelian variety $A$ with formal group $F$, how is the formal group $F^\ast$ of the dual abelian variety $A^{\vee}$ related to $F$? In general, for a formal group $F$, is there a concept of dual formal group $F^\ast$? If so, how is it defined? I think this is related to the cartier dual, but could you give a simple description of $F^*$?

Any reference or insight would be very helpful.

Comment: The theory of $p$-divisible groups (when $p$ is the residue characteristic of the ground field) is more suited to duality than that of formal groups.  The formal group more or less forgets about the étale part of the $p$-divisible group,  and similarly, the dual of a toric $p$-divisible group ($\mu_{p^\infty}$, say, whose formal group would be the multiplicative formal group law) is étale.

Comment: ACL: You've already said everything necessary; I am just linking the references
[Tate's classic][1] or [Serre's Seminaire Bourbaki][2]


  [1]: http://fhoermann.org/Tate%2520-%2520p-Divisible%2520Groups.pdf
  [2]: http://www.numdam.org/item?id=SB_1966-1968__10__73_0